# Android: how to change color of Options Menu on Click

Tags: android

By default Android shows Orange color on Options Menu when an item is selected.

[image]

How can I set my own color to the OptionsMenu on click??

Answer (score 0):

Options menu in android can be customized to set the background or change the text appearance. The background and text color in the menu couldn’t be changed using themes and styles. The android source code (data\res\layout\icon_menu_item_layout.xml)uses a custom item of class “com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItem”View for the menu layout. We can make changes in the above class to customize the menu. To achieve the same, use LayoutInflater factory class and set the background and text color for the view.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
                try{
                    LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // set the background drawable
                            view.setBackgroundColor(any color);

                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                } catch (InflateException e) {
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I had already seen this on some other post. Isn't there any simple solution to set the color ??

Comment: until now even i didnt get any simple solution. i did it as in above code only

Comment: I think this will change the default color of the OptionsMenu. But I dont want this. What I want is it should change the color on Click only.This will just change the default color of OptionsMenu

Comment: so you wanna to change it on click

Comment: thats what I have asked in the question

Comment: want to change only on focus?

Comment: selectors doesnt work here because if we use selectors we can't set the logo image. Any better answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file called `selector.xml` in your `drawable` folder then fill it with this..

Basically you are telling Android that you want to do something when an event occurs like a user clicks a `Button` or  focuses it etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Then set the icon of your Item which you use in Menu to this, like

`android:icon = "@drawable/selector"`,

For more on using StateListDrawable refer to [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-2-custom-listview/).

Comment: The colors in android:drawable="@color/blue" should be defined in color.xml file under values folder

Comment: Actually the Menu Item doesnt have the attribute "background".

Comment: Use android:panelFullBackground

Comment: see I edited the code, change android:icon proerty directly, it works for me.

Comment: See I am setting the icon image through this "android:icon" attribute only. If I use the selector and set the color,it will change the background color but cannot set the icon image. I think you understood.